# Opposite of @encode

Tags: objective-c, encoding, types, objective-c-runtime

Is there an opposite operator for `@encode`?

For example, when you do this: `@encode(int)`, you get `"i"`. I'd like to be able to do this: `@decode("i") myInt = 5;`

Is this possible? Does an operator exist to handle this?

Comment: Down this path lies madness.   C and C-derived languages really aren'd designed for this kind of dynamic, introspective, behaviors.

Comment: It's sort of possible to do this, if you want to mess around with libffi: [Mike Ash on trampolining into Blocks](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-05-06-a-tour-of-mablockclosure.html), but you can't actually declare a variable at compile time based on the type of another variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. `@encode` takes a type, and in C, it's not possible to return a type. (The `typeof()` operator is a GNU extension but it doesn't take a C string, so what you want is not possible.

You have two options. One: redesign your code. If you need this, you probably have a design problem.

Two, use dynamic memory allocation and write your own function that takes a type string and allocates memory accordingly.

Comment: The `typeof()` operator was the one I searched for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSGetSizeAndAlignment](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSGetSizeAndAlignment) to get the size and do the allocation.

```
NSUInteger size;
NSGetSizeAndAlignment(encoding, &size, NULL);
void* ptr = malloc(size);

if (strcmp(encoding, @encode(int)) == 0) {
    *(int*)ptr += 2;
} else if (strcmp(encoding, @encode(float)) == 0) {
    *(float*)ptr += 2.0;
}

free(ptr);
```

Answer (score -1):

umm, yeah.. there most certainly, ***is***...

```
           int five = 5;
__typeof(five) four = 4;

printf("@encode(int):%s\n", @encode(int));
printf("typeof(five):%s\n", @encode(__typeof(five)));
printf("typeof(four):%s\n", @encode(__typeof(four)));
```

➜

> *`@encode(int):i`*
>
> *`typeof(five):i`*
>
> *`typeof(four):i`*